# Cordova multiple logging writes fail

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, phonegap-build

I'm writing a log to file function to a file on the device.  When I write back to back entries, only one of the two get saved to file.  I am getting the pointer with a .seek call before each write, but it seems that the pointer is not updated or the file is not being closed.  I have confirmed that the 2 events are firing and the external log file is getting appended, its just missing one of the entries.

Here is the code:

```
function writetheLog(str) {

if(!logOb) return;


logOb.createWriter(gotFileWriter, function(){alert('fail')}); 

function gotFileWriter(fileWriter) {
  fileWriter.onwrite = function(evt) {
    //alert("write success");
    console.log("write success");
    };    

fileWriter.onwriteend = function(evt) {
  alert("write end");
  console.log("write end");
  };    

fileWriter.onerror = function(evt) {
  console.log("write error");
};    

fileWriter.seek(fileWriter.length);
var blob = new Blob([str], {type:'text/plain'});
fileWriter.write(blob); }
```

Is there some way to do this async or force the pointer to update on each call?

Comment: You should consider adding more tags in order to get more attention to your question